# new form created in main form is not defined

Tags: python, class, oop, pyqt5

I created a class of MainWindow and a class of FirstParty which is a second form. I created a object of FirstParty with the name of firstPartyForm in MainWindow class but when i run my program it shows that the firstPartyForm is not defined do you mean FirstParty.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to try to improve your code readability by adding blank lines at least between function/class definitions (see the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)). Also, you should not use globals. And checking the state of two checkboxes by matching their name in a function that then still refers to the objects and also returns a string is completely nonsensical.

Answer (score 0):

check your AddFirstParty.ui file, probably there is no firstPartyForm name

Comment: firstPartyForm is object created in createFirstPartForm()

Comment: problem is now solved